# alignat align two sums under each other

Tags: align, amsmath, alignat

This

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}
f(a) &= \lim_{s} \frac{1}{2 z} \int_{-w}^{+e}\int_{-r}^{+t} g(q)\cdot h(q) d x d y  &\\
    &= \lim_{s} \frac{1}{3s} &\Bigg\{  \sum_{w} \int_{-r}^{+t} g(q+e)\cdot h(q) d x d y d x d y &\\
    & &  \sum_{w} \int_{-r}^{+t} g(q)\cdot h(q) d x d y d x d y &\Bigg\} \\ 
\end{alignat*}
```

Produces this:
[image]

Obviously, the space between the fraction and curly bracket is not intended, what I wanted to do was to align the second sum under the first one like it is done [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396180/alignat-with-mixed-left-right-alignment). What is incorrect? (I want to do it with alignat without getting too complex like nested alignemets)

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a case for `split` with a nested `aligned` or `multlined` environment.

A couple of notes

1. `dx` should be preceded by a thin space; it's easy to forget it, so I provide a `\diff` command that adds it automatically;
2. `\Bigg` is too large and it should be in the `\Biggl` and `\Biggr` varieties anyhow; I used `\biggl` and `\biggr`;
3. in the `aligned` solution, there should be a `\!` before `\sum` to avoid an unwanted thin space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\newcommand\diff{\mathop{}\!d}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
f(a)
&= \lim_{s} \frac{1}{2z} \int_{-w}^{+e}\int_{-r}^{+t} g(q)\cdot h(q)\diff x\diff y
\\
&= \lim_{s} \frac{1}{3s} \biggl\{
   \begin{aligned}[t]
     &\!\sum_{w} \int_{-r}^{+t} g(q+e)\cdot h(q) \diff x \diff y \diff x \diff y \\
     &\!\sum_{w} \int_{-r}^{+t} g(q)\cdot h(q) \diff x \diff y \diff x \diff y 
   \biggr\}
   \end{aligned}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
f(a)
&= \lim_{s} \frac{1}{2z} \int_{-w}^{+e}\int_{-r}^{+t} g(q)\cdot h(q)\diff x\diff y
\\
&= \lim_{s} \frac{1}{3s} \biggl\{
   \begin{multlined}[t]
     \sum_{w} \int_{-r}^{+t} g(q+e)\cdot h(q) \diff x \diff y \diff x \diff y \\
     \sum_{w} \int_{-r}^{+t} g(q)\cdot h(q) \diff x \diff y \diff x \diff y 
   \biggr\}
   \end{multlined}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

A combination of an `\hphantom{\Bigg\{}` and some additional alignment points gives good results:

[image]

### Notes:

- The `alignat*=` environment produces as many `rl` (right/left) pairs as specified in the first parameter and does not insert additional space that the `align` environment does, so you need to insert the space that is desired between the alignment points (this was not needed in this case).
- The double `&&` ensure that the subsequent columns are also left aligned.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% include amsmath

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{4}
f(a) 
    &= \lim_{s} \frac{1}{2 z} &&                    \int_{-w}^{+e}\int_{-r}^{+t} g(q)\cdot h(q) d x d y      & \\
    &= \lim_{s} \frac{1}{3s}  &&           \Bigg\{  \sum_{w} \int_{-r}^{+t} g(q+e)\cdot h(q) d x d y d x d y & \\
    &                         && \hphantom{\Bigg\{} \sum_{w} \int_{-r}^{+t} g(q)\cdot h(q) d x d y d x d y   & \Bigg\} \\ 
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why does the solution with simple `alignat` not work, since i merely copied what works from the link that I mention in the question and just used different content?

Comment: @leosenko: The solution you linked to employs `\mathrlap` so what you have here is not really identical to that solution.  There are lots of different way to do alignments -- I only presented what came naturally to me: Select the desired alighnemt points and use a single `&` where you want the text _before_ to be `r` aligned and the text following to be `l` aligned. A double `&&`skips the `r` align component and make the text following `l` aligned.  Also updated answer to attempt to explain this.

Answer (score 2):

A solution with an `aligned` environment nested in a `align*`. I  also propose a different alignment, and an improvement for the spacing of differential symbols:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}

     \begin{document}

   \begin{align*}
    f(a) &= \lim_{s} \frac{1}{2 z} \int_{-w}^{+e}\int_{-r}^{+t} g(q)\cdot h(q)\, d x\,d y &\\
        &= \lim_{s} \frac{1}{3s}\begin{aligned}[t]\Bigg\{ & \sum_{w} \int_{-r}^{+t} g(q+e)\cdot h(q) \,d x\,d y\,d x\,d y \\
        & \sum_{w} \int_{-r}^{+t} g(q)\cdot h(q) \,d x\, d y \, d x\, d y\, \Bigg\}\end{aligned}
    \end{align*}
    \bigskip

   \begin{align*}
    f(a) &= \lim_{s} \frac{1}{2 z} \int_{-w}^{+e}\int_{-r}^{+t} g(q)\cdot h(q) \,d x\,d y &\\
    &= \lim_{s} \frac{1}{3s}\begin{aligned}[t]\Bigg\{\sum_{w} \int_{-r}^{+t} g(q+e)\cdot h(q) \,d x\,d y\,d x\,d y & \\
   \sum_{w} \int_{-r}^{+t} g(q)\cdot h(q)\,d x\,d y\,d x\,d y &\,\Bigg\}\end{aligned}
    \end{align*}

     \end{document}
```

[image]