# Differentiation symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols

Generally, I use `mathrm{d}` for the differentiation symbol in math mode, `x\,\mathrm{d}x`? However, I sometimes feel that the spacing is not accurate. What is best practice, theoretical computer science and pure mathematics.

Comment: There is also \DeclareMathOperator (amsmath page 19).

Comment: Thanks. Basically, I do not know what is the best practice for the spacing between the x, d, and x. And do we generally use \mathrm{d}?

Comment: Typographic isues are discussed at [What's the proper way to typeset a differential operator?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14822/4301). Solutions are available at [Should I \mathrm the d in my integrals?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60545/4301), [Better automatic spacing of differential d?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/178946/4301) and [alignat align two sums under each other](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/466418/4301) and include sign `\mathop{}\!d` and  `\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}`, among others.  The second reference also references a _TUGboat)_ exactly article on this topic.

Comment: I read the above links. I guess it is a long discussion, and I find which one is more suitable one.

Comment: Which ever solution you decide to use, I'd highly recommend you wrap it in a macro to allow you to easliy change it in the future should you desire to do so.  And, [welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).

Comment: If you are submitting an article to a particular journal, take a look at already published articles in that journal in a similar subject area, and do what is done there, mediated by a macro that allows you to style it "on the fly" so to speak.